# Laravel Echo does not output the event channel pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

I just started learning laravel pusher.

I have installed Composer Pusher and got the key from the pusher website
I've looked at getting starter and seen info from several sources on how to install and configure it about 'laravel echo'.

but I have a problem, that when I look in the browser console, the js location for pusher is not found (/js/pusher.js.map)

even though I had "npm install" and "npm run watch".

status is still the same, so window.Echo.channel('myChannel').listener('MessageCreate', function(data) {
console.log(data)
})

does not appear in the browser console. the status only appears that the file "/js/pusher.js.min was not found with status 400.

how do you think about how to solve it?

1. first add event with name "MessageCreate", then add impelement ShoulBroadcast
   `php artisan make:event MessageCreate` -> `Class MessageCreate impelemnt ShouldBroadcast`
2. add key and cluster in file .env
3. install composer pusher
   `composer require pusher/pusher-http-laravel`
4. then npm pusher
   `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js`
5. install npm and npm run watch
6. go to blade and add tag script
7. go to browser and open inspect then menu console.
8. no result just information about `not found 127.0.0.1/js/pusher.js.map`

i need to solved about `not found 127.0.0.1/js/pusher.js.map`

Comment: did you uncomment the laravel echo instance in the `bootstrap.js` ?

Comment: there is already bootstrap.js in resource/js/ folder